# android connectivity with localhost

Tags: android

1. I have configured the open source moodle 2.0 on my laptop.
2. For that I have installed XAMPP server on which local host is running on Browser once Apache and MySQL are started using the XAMPP panel.
3. i.e. the moodle database is in the http://localhost/
4. under the moodle database there are 275 tables.
5. In the table `mdl_user` the username and password are stored.
6. I just want to access the login creating my own interface on the android emulator. (without opening the browser)

i.e. my android app should match the username and password stored in the single row of the `mdl_user` table and then grant him/her login (login successful).

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

**Server side**

1) You have to made a script file in server-side that can accept your username and password and authenticate if authentication is success then you can response positive else response negative

**Client side**

1) You have to make HTTP connection to the server

[ref1](http://w3mentor.com/learn/java/android-development/android-http-services/example-of-http-get-request-using-httpclient-in-android/)

[ref2](http://www.androidsnippets.com/executing-a-http-post-request-with-httpclient)

2) Give appropriate permission to menifest

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

3) if you are sending response from server in xml then you have to Parse xml

and also remember one thing

If You are testing localhost server then URL for Emulator must be like this

```
http://IP Address of your Computer/~dharmendra/
```

Comment: i have to make a script file in server-side that can accept my username and password and authenticate if authentication is success then i can response positive else response negative

Comment: Also, if you are in the emulator, you can access the host machine at http://10.0.2.2

Comment: i have to make a script file in server-side that can accept my username and password and authenticate if authentication is success then i can response positive else response negative..

Comment: @anubhav then what is your problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Each instance of the emulator runs behind a virtual router/firewall service that isolates it from your development machine’s network interfaces and settings and from the internet. An emulated device can not see your development machine or other emulator instances on the network. Instead, it sees only that it is connected through Ethernet to a router/firewall.

i think this post can help you
http://red23rockets.com/?p=28